# How can one show that scattering time scales with temperature as

Tags: scattering, conductors

Drude's law
$\sigma=\frac{ne^2\tau}{m}$
involves the scattering time $\tau$, which, as mentioned [in this short article](https://physics.aps.org/articles/v13/20), at low temperatures typically scales as $\tau\propto T^{-2}$.

The author states that this is to be expected in the quasiparticle picture. How can this be shown to be generally true, or where can I find a derivation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: use Fermi's golden rule to calculate the scattering rate for a Fermi liquid. The result is that the rate $1/\tau$ varies as $T^2$ (and also as $(\varepsilon-\varepsilon_{\rm Fermi})^2$). Hence the $T^{-2}$ dependence of $\tau$ in this quasi-particle picture.

For a more precise hint: a quote from the thesis "Condensed Matter Applications of AdS/CFT" by Andrea Amoretti: ([link to relevant chapter/equation](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-3-319-61875-3%2F1.pdf#equation.A.54))

> In most of the qualitative arguments of the temperature scaling of the resistivity in a Fermi liquid, it is argued that the famous *T*<sup>2</sup> scaling is due to the scattering between quasi-particles. Actually this kind of interaction, as we have just proven, does not contribute by itself to the resistivity, and it is more precise to say that it is the combined action of the quasi-particle scattering and the Umklapp scattering which generates the *T*<sup>2</sup> scaling of the resistivity.